# Remove each individual image from localPath by using NSDocumentDirectory

Tags: ios, objective-c

Hi i am storing some images in `NSDocuments` directory in one folder i am able to store files but i am not able to remove each individual. When i am trying to remove file complete folder going to be remove.

Here is my sample code to store and remove.

This is the path i'm getting ehile storing file:

```
/Users/emantras/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0.3/Applications/E5D35472-6845-4BCE-98CC-3F852FF52212/Documents/uplo‌​adedpicturecard/ram_1394445189.065911.jpg
```

But when i delete i am getting path like:

```
/Users/emantras/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0.3/Applications/E5D35472-6845-4BCE-98CC-3F852FF52212/Documents/uplo‌​adedpicturecard
```

Can you help me through my code:

```
-(void)saveFile
{
 UIImage *imageToUpload = [pictureCardInfo objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    DBWrapper *dbwrapper = [DBWrapper sharedWrapper];
    NSTimeInterval timeStamp = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
    // NSTimeInterval is defined as double
    NSNumber *timeStampObj = [NSNumber numberWithDouble: timeStamp];

  //  ////NSLog(@"image file name: %@",timeStampObj);
    fileName1 =[_txtView.text stringByAppendingString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"_%@",timeStampObj]];

    fileName1 = [fileName1 stringByAppendingString:@".jpg"];

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
   filePath = [[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/uploadedpicturecard"] stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName1];

    ////NSLog(@"filePath===>%@",filePath);

    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageToUpload, 1.0)];
[imageData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES]
}

-(void)removeFile
{
 NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectoryPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

        fileName1 = [fileName1 stringByAppendingString:@".jpg"];
        filePath = [[documentsDirectoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/uploadedpicturecard"] stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName1];
        ////NSLog(@"FileName====>%@",filePath);

        NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
        [fileManager removeItemAtPath:filePath error:NULL];
}
```

Comment: Wgats the value of filePath in the remove method ?

Comment: `stringByAppendingPathComponent:` does automatically add the / so it is one too much here: @"/uploadedpicturecard"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15017902/delete-specified-file-from-document-directory

Answer (score 0):

cOrderPath is the path of the Directory where all images are saved.

Now first call below code which will take all the images count before deletion

```
  NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
        filesForDetails = [fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:self.cOrderPath error:nil];

        iOrderCount=[filesForDetails count];
        iIndex=0;
```

After that call CallForDeletion function

```
[self CallForDeletion];
```

later on this function will recursively delete all the images. Once `iIndex==iOrderCount` then return from the function

```
-(void)CallForDeletion
    {
        NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
        filesForDetails = [fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:self.cOrderPath error:nil];
         NSString *file=filesForDetails[0];
         NSString *cFilePath=[self.cOrderPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:file];
         [fileManager removeItemAtPath:cFilePath error:nil];
        iIndex=+1;

        if(iIndex==iOrderCount)
        {
          //Done with Deletion so return
        return;
        }

        [self CallForDeletion];//To call recursively
    }
```

Comment: what is filesForDetails, iIndex and iOrderCount?

Comment: filesForDetails is NSArray. iIndex and iOrderCount are int

Answer (score 0):

This will work...
I tasted it. and filePath is your full path of your item.
you can check your file path is right or wrong with NSLog.
The code is....

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSError *error;
[fileManager removeItemAtPath:filePath error:&error];


if (error){
    NSLog(@"getting error now delete == %@", error);
}
```

Hope this help...