# Deleting URL not working swift 3

Tags: swift, swift3

What am I doing wrong here?
All I am trying to delete a given file, and all the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/filemanager/1413590-removeitem) and [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15017902/delete-specified-file-from-document-directory) I've seen make it seem like this should be working.

```
func deleteThisFile(fileToDelete: String) {
    let tempLocalDir = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first
    do {
        let directoryContents = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: tempLocalDir!, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: [])
        let tempList = directoryContents.filter{ $0.absoluteString.contains(fileToDelete) }

        //tried these things:
        try FileManager.removeItem(tempList.first) // Argument labels '(_:)' do not match any available overloads
       /*
        * try FileManager.removeItem(at: tempList.first!) // Ambiguous reference to member 'removeItem(atPath:)'
        * 
        * try FileManager.removeItem(atPath: (tempList.first?.absoluteString)!) // Ambiguous reference to member 'removeItem(atPath:)'
        */ 

    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

The one that is not commented is what the FileManager.removeItem auto prompts for when I am typing it.

Any clarification on what is wrong would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Swift 3 you should use `removeItem(at:)` which is an instance method of `NSFileManager`. And you need to unwrap the optional before handing over to `NSFileManager`.

```
if let url = tempList.first {
    try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: url)
}
```

Comment: why is '.default' needed? I mean, it seems to work, and I'm grateful, I just don't understand why the .default is needed

Comment: Because you need an instance of `NSFileManager` or `FileManager` to call `removeItem(at:)`. Instead of using that singleton you can also instantiate a new `FileManager` but you always need an instance to invoke that method.